# How to remove a background image from a button?

Tags: swift, uibutton

I would like to know how to remove a backgroundImage from a button. My button has an image using code:

```
 self.btnSelectServicio.setBackgroundImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "fondo_transparente"), for: .normal)
```

But now when I press other button I would like to remove the image background.
I was looking for a function that removes it but I did not find it.

I tried using .disable but it is not working.

I was searching on Stack Overflow but all of the answers almost are from 5-8 years ago and they are in Objective-C.

Comment: Pass `nil` for the image to remove it.

Comment: Thank you so much friend, That helped me

Answer (score 0):

You should set `nil` as image.

For more elegant code, you can implement an easy `extension`:

```
extension UIButton {
    func removeBackgroundImage(for state: UIControl.State) {
        setBackgroundImage(nil, for: state)
    }
}
```

so now you can use it like:

```
self.btnSelectServicio.removeBackgroundImage(for: .normal)
```